# "I woke up at 6am" or "I waked up at 6am"?

Tags: verbs, past-tense

I would like to know which one is right and more common to use?

"I woke up at 6am" or "I waked up at 6am"?

Comment: About "which one is more common", [look at this graph.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=woke+up%2Fwaked+up&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28woke%20up%20/%20waked%20up%29%3B%2Cc0)  "Woke up" is about 70 times as common as "waked up", and its popularity has been increasing rapidly since about 1970.

Answer (score 2):

### Technically speaking

According to http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-wake.html ,
both forms (woke/waked) are correct.

### Usage-wise

At least for American English, in my experience "woke" as the past tense of "wake" is always used. Personally, I never knew that "waked" was a proper form of "wake" until reading the above link.

From the answer by @Janus Bahs Jacquet in the following link:

> In current English, woke is the standard past tense of wake, both
>   transitive and intransitive, causative or not; waked is marked as
>   nonstandard (dialectical) or archaic, and it’s nowhere near as common
>   as woke.

Answer (score 0):

Although I can say "woke" is the more common form used but for further details I'd suggest you to have a look at "[Past tense of wake: is there a difference between “waked”, and “woke”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221905/past-tense-of-wake-is-there-a-difference-between-waked-and-woke)" on English Language and Usage.

The accepted answer says (in part)

> In current English, woke is the standard past tense of wake, both transitive and intransitive, causative or not; waked is marked as nonstandard (dialectical) or archaic, and it’s nowhere near as common as woke.

Comment: Please read over [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/273494) The information may be somewhere in the question you've linked, but you need to describe how the information at that link applies to *this* question instead of making people guess. Explain why you are asking someone to look at that link and maybe quote some helpful information from it and you may get some up-votes. I've edited you answer as an example - you may want to edit it and ad more of your own thoughts.